# Async find matching number from object that includes an array of numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to ASYNCHRONOUSLY return objects which are filtered by category. Simply, I want to load my products ASYNCHRONOUSLY by category.

I have a function called 'getProductByID' that finds product by given id

```js
  getProductByID(id: number): Observable<ProductModel> {
    return of(ProductsList.find((product) => product.id === id));
  } //it works fine

//I tried to create same function for categories,
//but I dont know how to find number from the array

  getProductsByCategory2(selectedCategory: CategoryModel): Observable<ProductModel[]> {
     return of(ProductsList.find((product) => product.category === selectedCategory)
   } //it doesn't work

  getProductsByCategory(selectedCategory: CategoryModel): ProductModel[] {
    const products: ProductModel[] = [];
    for (const product of ProductsList) {
      for (const category of product.category) {
        if (category === selectedCategory.id) {
          products.push(product);
        }
      }
    }
    return products;
  }// this function works fine too, but it doesn't return products asynchronously
```

I need to find all products that matches with given category id. Each product can contain more than 1 category.

Comment: Using `of()` doesn't make things asynchronous. But if that's what you want, just do `return of (products)`in your "working" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter method from rxjs/operators in your service, or other place, where you get data.

```
return of(ProductsList.pipe(
    map(result => result.filter(item => item.userId == 1)) // here set your filtering 
))
```

and then subscribe to filtered data

Answer (score 1):

Find function get the first matching element, so try filter function.

Pay attention:
In your function getProductsByCategory2 you compare product.category to selectedCategory. Object comparison in js is made with reference, use primitive value to compare more efficiently.